# what is log : function() {} in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code in a quiz and I am fairly new to javascript. Although I know how the function works, still can anyone explain me the 3rd line of the code.
What this log: function() {} means:

```
var abc = function() {
    return {
      log : function() {
        console.log(this.val);
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: log as the only field of the object returned by outer function (which is assigned to abc) is initialized as the function body next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an object property whose value is a function. If you do:

```
var x = abc();
```

you can then do:

```
x.log()
```

to call the function. Here's a full example:

```js
var abc = function() {
    return {
      log : function() {
        console.log(this.val);
      }
    };
}

var x = abc();
x.val = "This is the value";
var y = abc();
y.val = "This is y's value";
x.log();
y.log();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a follow up question on it. How is the above function different from the following:

    var abc = function(){
        return{
          log : () => {
           console.log(this.val);
          }
        };
    }

Comment: @peggy.go See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Answer (score 0):

This would return an object as `{log: function()}`. It is a normal JS object, which looks like `{key:value}`. Read more about JS objects here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

I am presuming the question is about what `this` resolves to. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . Better yet, I can recommend you Kyle Simpson's [this & Object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) book from the '*You Don't Know JS*' series.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `key` of an object and its `value` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

**log** as the only field of the object returned by the outer function (which is assigned to variable **abc**) is initialized as the function body next to it.

Answer (score 0):

To better help you understand it, I'll structure the code given with pseudo code

```
OBJECT abc IS A FUNCTION THAT DOES
    RETURN ANONYMOUS OBJECT
        LOG TO CONSOLE this.val
```

Let's examine the function declaration that you are most familiar with.

```
function myFunction() {
    //do stuff
}
```

In the example given, you are being shown **anonymous functions**. In the example above, the function is declared with a name, which is `myFunction`. But with anonymous functions, no name has to be given when declaring. So in basis, the function *has no name*, making it anonymous.

The point of a function is to avoid repetitive code. So giving functions a name allows you to call them from anywhere. With anonymous functions, you cannot call them unless assigning them to a variable.

Anonymous functions are used when usually grouping code. Whether the group of code is for an `event listener` or for other things.

You can learn more about anonymous functions [here](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/06/10/javascript-anonymous-functions.html).

Also in this example is **anonymous objects**. You are probably familiar with giving objects names. But what `return` is returning is an anonymous object. Within the anonymous object is what we're about to look at.

An object structure looks similar to this:

```
objectName
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

So in this case, the anonymous object that `return` is returning has a key called `log`. The value for this key is an anonymous function that logs `this.val` to a console.

You can learn more about objects [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Happy Coding,

Farouk

Comment: Your "anonymous function" is actually a function declaration without a name, which is a syntax error (function declarations must have a name). An anonymous function is formed by a function expression where the optional name is omitted. Regarding "*Usually with anonymous functions, you cannot call them*", that would make them pretty useless. They are typically either called immediately (an immediately invoked function expression or IIFE) or assigned to a variable, parameter, property, etc. so that they can be called later.

Answer (score 0):

`abc()` returns a plain object, where properties and values can be set at the object. Within the functions of the object `this` would reference the object instance. We can set `.val` of `this` to a value then call `abc()` object `.log()` method

```js
var abc = function() {
    return {
      log : function() {
        console.log(this.val);
      }
    };
}

var def = abc();

def.val = 123;

def.log();
```

`this.val` can also be set a value at `abc()` call by defining default parameters

```js
var abc = function(val = 123) {
    return {
      log : function() {
        console.log(this.val);
      },
      val
    };
}

var def = abc(); // optionally pass parameters to `abc()` call

def.log();
```